# Cannot delete image from original path after copying to destination

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-contentresolver, android-fileprovider

My requirement is :-

-> When I pick an image from "Recents" (i.e. ACTION_GET_CONTENT), I expect the image to generate a copy at "Android/data/com.devarshi.galleryapp/files" and delete the image from it's original path. Generating copy and deleting the image from it's original path, will allow me to replicate the "moving" operation.

The below provided code performs the operation of copying image to expected destination sucessfully. However, the deletion operation is not effective. :-

```
public static String getPath(Context context, Uri uri) {

    // DocumentProvider
    if (DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }
            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }
            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};
            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {column};
    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}

public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
 */
public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
 */
public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

/**
 * @param uri The Uri to check.
 * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
 */
public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public void browseClick() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    //intent.putExtra("browseCoa", itemToBrowse);
    //Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload");
    try {
        //startActivityForResult(chooser, FILE_SELECT_CODE);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a File to Upload"), FILE_SELECT_CODE);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("browseClick :" + ex);//android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FILE_SELECT_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                Uri uri = data.getData();

                File file = new File(String.valueOf(uri));
                int filesize = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(file.length() / 1024));

                if (filesize >= FILE_SIZE_LIMIT) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The selected file is too large. Select a new file with size less than 2mb", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    String mimeType = getContentResolver().getType(uri);
                    if (mimeType == null) {
                        String path = getPath(this, uri);
                        if (path == null) {
                            filename = FilenameUtils.getName(uri.toString());
                        } else {
                            File file1 = new File(path);
                            filename = file1.getName();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                        Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
                        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                        filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
                        String size = Long.toString(returnCursor.getLong(sizeIndex));
                    }
                    File fileSave = getExternalFilesDir(null);
                    String sourcePath = getExternalFilesDir(null).toString();
                    try {
                        moveFile(uri, String.valueOf(new File(sourcePath + "/" + filename)), this);
                        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: filename " + filename);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: Error" + e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void moveFile(Uri uri, String outputPath, Context context) {

    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {

        in = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        out = new FileOutputStream(outputPath);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int read;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        }

        in.close();
        in = null;

        // write the output file
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        out = null;

        // delete the original file
        String filePath = getPath(context, uri);

        if (filePath != null) {
            new File(filePath).delete();
        }
        
        //new File(uri).delete;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe1) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
    }

  }
}
```

The below provided snippet is not effective. However, I have provided the whole code of ACTION_GET_CONTENT (i.e.opening "recents" successfully) in case of existence of any errors in it :-

```
    // delete the original file
    String filePath = getPath(context, uri);

    if (filePath != null) {
        new File(filePath).delete();
    }
```

I have specified below mentioned properties and permissions for File operations in my project:-

```
1) Permissions :-
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

2) Properties :-
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.devarshi.galleryapp.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
         android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
         android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

Kindly provide some suggestions I can try to implement for successfully removing image from it's original path. I have tried debugging and evaluating expression for deletion operation.

Comment: @blackapps I have modified my question as per your suggestion. I have accurately addressed my exact issue of image not getting deleted in it. Thank you for guidance.

Comment: @blackapps I am sorry for misunderstanding. I have modified the subject.

Comment: `getPath(Context context, Uri uri) ` Please throw away that function. Dont try to get a path to begin with. If ACTION_GET_CONTENT gives you an uri you should use the uri to delete the file behind it. Also for copying to another storage location you do not need getPath().l

Comment: `File file = new File(String.valueOf(uri));` Impossible code. You cannot use the File class for an Uri.

Comment: The only thing you need in onActivityResult() after determining fileName is:  `String destinationPath = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName).getAbsolutePath(); moveFile(data.getData(), destinationPath, this);`  That will copy your file. After that you can try to delete the original.